# Why does nginx cost money on AWS Marketplace

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm looking at running nginx on a m1.small instance. I noticed in the [marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00A04GAG4/ref=srh_res_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-5&qid=1356724832156) you can deploy an ami but it costs $0.024 an hour. I though nginx was an open source, free web server. What is the reason for this additional fee?

Comment: If you don't want to pay for nginx support, you can always install it yourself in whatever AMI you want.  But then, you don't get support from nginx's developers.  As a general note, "open source, free" does not mean that the developers will drop whatever they're doing and promptly reply to your installation and product support questions.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but I suspect the reason for the downvotes was that the answer was plainly present in the link you provided.

Answer (score 7):

Because they chose to charge for it.

As the description says, the money goes to the nginx developers, and you receive product support directly from them.

So you are paying the nginx developers for support for nginx.